# htaccess - append html or php based on URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rules which adds .html to all requests so that if a user navigates to `www.mysite.com/support`, they see my `www.mysite.com/support.html` page:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

How can I change this so that for specific urls, it adds .php instead of .html:

- /support => should go to www.mysite.com/support.php
- /contact => should go to www.mysite.com/contact.php
- /everything else  => should go to www.mysite.com/...html

Thanks.

Comment: `Rewrite rule ^support /support.php`

Comment: do I add that first, last or does it matter? thnx

Comment: before any rules that'd also match and produce an undesired rewrite, basically.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your `.htaccess` to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^support /support.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact /contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: that didn't work, this line `RewriteRule ^support /support.php [L]` is throwing server error: **The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.**

Comment: Update to my previous comment: When I test exactly what you suggested, no page on my site works. If I move that rule to the 2nd line, all pages work except the support page...it throws the same error.